# In Linux, efficiently split a large file vertically

Tags: linux, split, large-files

Is there an analogue of the `split` command which can split a file by columns rather than rows, efficiently?

I have a 30GB csv file with ~15k columns and ~150k rows, and I would like to split it into say, 10 files with 1500 columns each.

I tried using `awk` to split out the file into 15k files, but it is unworkably slow.

```
awk -F, { for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) print $i >> i } file.csv
```

Comment: If the csv is well-formed it would not be too difficult to write a small program for that. See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15669765/905902 (just add a comma counter/index and an array of file-pointers and you are done)

Comment: Thanks! Are you suggesting that this will be much faster than awk?

Comment: I don't think that AWK is that slow (unless you need multiple passes over the data) Trivial programs like this are only limited by the disk I/O speed.

Comment: Well, in this case it doesn't seem to be. The base file that I'm working off, I was able to write in ~5 minutes(Same amount of writing work). Based on progress so far, the awk command is expected to run for several days.

Comment: You could write the equivalent program in C... And you might also try `cut`

Comment: Thank you, cut was significantly faster and served my purpose (About 20 minutes). Custom C program was even faster, taking 10 minutes.